# Where can I download the Windows Phone 8.1 developer preview when it becomes available?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

After watching Microsoft's Build conference, I learnt about Windows Phone 8.1 and decided that I want to download the Windows Phone 8.1 developer preview.

Where can I download the Windows Phone 8.1 developer preview when it becomes available?

Comment: I would guess Microsoft... just copying and pasting your title into google worked as well. https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is overly simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download the app [Preview for Developers](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/preview-for-developers/178ac8a1-6519-4a0b-960c-038393741e96) on your Windows Phone.
2. Use this app to enable yourself for the `Preview for Developers`. You must have an Active Windows Phone dev center account or an active app studio account or a dev unlocked phone.
3. Once Windows Phone 8.1 developer preview gets released, you'll be able to download the update from `Settings` and update the phone as you normally do.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose the SDK would be available in normal [Windows Phone SDK download site](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk), also there appears to be some 8.1 stuff already available in there.